# How to calculate width and height of text in jspdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf

I'm facing some issues while creating tables in [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). I could not find any good related docs, but if anyone knows one, please share.

I found two related methods:

1) `doc.getStringUnitWidth(text, {widths:12,kerning:2});`

2) `doc.getTextDimensions(text)`

What does *widths* and *kerning* mean in the first method? What should I provide? Which method should I use to get the width and height of text?

My goal is to solve some issues related to overlapping cell content, wrapping of text and text overflow relative to the page width.

Comment: refer this example https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/basic.html

Comment: thanks :), But I need table api example. I want to understand it. do you have any link of it?

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/a7de195d34b8a5a55ce2dc05d4dc779dbb918084/jspdf.plugin.cell.js 
this is the plugin for the table generation

Answer (score 43):

You might want to look at the [AutoTable](https://github.com/someatoms/jsPDF-AutoTable) plugin for generating tables with jsPDF. I found the built in plugin hard to work with and isn't documented at all.

The best way I have found to calculate the width is simply doing this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var width = doc.getTextWidth('Text');
console.log(width);
```

If you really need to calculate the height `getDimensions()` might be an option. However, it is not pixel perfect and looking at the source I doubt it will work for anything but `pt`. Here is an example:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
var dim = doc.getTextDimensions('Text');
console.log(dim); // Object {w: 24.149968818897642, h: 19.499975433070865}
```

Comment: If you just need the text width, I suggest to give `getTextWidth` a try.

Comment: I don't remember seeing a getTextWidth in jspdf. How would you use it?

Comment: getTextWidth is not in jsPDF

Comment: You can see implementation of getTextWidth here https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/src/modules/annotations.js#L398

Answer (score 8):

I found this question looking for answers to a similar issue. Unfortunately, the answers provided did not solve my problem, but I figure what I did find out may help other people stumbling onto this question.

As already mentioned, the .getStringUnitWidth(text) will return the width of a string (in pt). I could never find any explanation of the options like "kerning" or "widths" in the documentation or in the actual .js file. I also noticed with my own usage that this method was actually underestimating widths by ~10%, which started to add up very quickly. Finally, this did not account for fonts that were bold, italicized or bold and italicized.

Since I required a high level of accuracy, I ended up calculating the width of each character on my own and using this to calculate a string width (by totaling the width of each character in a string).

Below are the font widths at size 1 (in pt) for each character accepted by jsPDF in the 3 default fonts (helvetica, times, courier):

```
helvetica
char    unicode   normal   bold     italic   bolditalic
        32        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278
!       33        0.278    0.333    0.278    0.333
"       34        0.355    0.474    0.355    0.474
#       35        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
$       36        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
%       37        0.889    0.889    0.889    0.889
&       38        0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722
'       39        0.191    0.238    0.191    0.238
(       40        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333
)       41        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333
*       42        0.389    0.389    0.389    0.389
+       43        0.584    0.584    0.584    0.584
,       44        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278
-       45        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333
.       46        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278
/       47        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278
0       48        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
1       49        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
2       50        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
3       51        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
4       52        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
5       53        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
6       54        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
7       55        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
8       56        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
9       57        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
:       58        0.278    0.333    0.278    0.333
;       59        0.278    0.333    0.278    0.333
<       60        0.584    0.584    0.584    0.584
=       61        0.584    0.584    0.584    0.584
>       62        0.584    0.584    0.584    0.584
?       63        0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611
@       64        1.015    0.975    1.015    0.975
A       65        0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722
B       66        0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722
C       67        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722
D       68        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722
E       69        0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667
F       70        0.611    0.611    0.611    0.611
G       71        0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778
H       72        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722
I       73        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278
J       74        0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556
K       75        0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722
L       76        0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611
M       77        0.833    0.833    0.833    0.833
N       78        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722
O       79        0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778
P       80        0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667
Q       81        0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778
R       82        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722
S       83        0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667
T       84        0.611    0.611    0.611    0.611
U       85        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722
V       86        0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667
W       87        0.944    0.944    0.944    0.944
X       88        0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667
Y       89        0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667
Z       90        0.611    0.611    0.611    0.611
[       91        0.278    0.333    0.278    0.333
\       92        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278
]       93        0.278    0.333    0.278    0.333
^       94        0.469    0.584    0.469    0.584
_       95        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
`       96        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333
a       97        0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556
b       98        0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611
c       99        0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556
d       100       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
e       101       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
f       102       0.278    0.333    0.278    0.333                      
g       103       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
h       104       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
i       105       0.222    0.278    0.222    0.278                      
j       106       0.222    0.278    0.222    0.278                      
k       107       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
l       108       0.222    0.278    0.222    0.278                      
m       109       0.833    0.889    0.833    0.889                      
n       110       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
o       111       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
p       112       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
q       113       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
r       114       0.333    0.389    0.333    0.389                      
s       115       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
t       116       0.278    0.333    0.278    0.333                      
u       117       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
v       118       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
w       119       0.722    0.778    0.722    0.778                      
x       120       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
y       121       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
z       122       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
{       123       0.334    0.389    0.334    0.389                      
|       124       0.260    0.280    0.260    0.280                      
}       125       0.334    0.389    0.334    0.389                      
~       126       0.584    0.584    0.584    0.584                      
€       128       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
‚       130       0.222    0.278    0.222    0.278                      
ƒ       131       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
„       132       0.333    0.500    0.333    0.500                      
…       133       1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000                      
†       134       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
‡       135       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
ˆ       136       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
‰       137       1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000                      
Š       138       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
‹       139       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
Œ       140       1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000                      
Ž       142       0.611    0.611    0.611    0.611                      
‘       145       0.222    0.278    0.222    0.278                      
’       146       0.222    0.278    0.222    0.278                      
“       147       0.333    0.500    0.333    0.500                      
”       148       0.333    0.500    0.333    0.500                      
•       149       0.350    0.350    0.350    0.350                      
–       150       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
—       151       1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000                      
˜       152       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
™       153       1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000                      
š       154       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
›       155       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
œ       156       0.944    0.944    0.944    0.944                      
ž       158       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
Ÿ       159       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
        160       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
¡       161       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
¢       162       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
£       163       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
¤       164       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
¥       165       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
¦       166       0.260    0.280    0.260    0.280                      
§       167       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
¨       168       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
©       169       0.737    0.737    0.737    0.737                      
ª       170       0.370    0.370    0.370    0.370                      
«       171       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
¬       172       0.584    0.584    0.584    0.584                      
-       173       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
®       174       0.737    0.737    0.737    0.737                      
¯       175       0.552    0.552    0.552    0.552                      
°       176       0.400    0.400    0.400    0.400                      
±       177       0.549    0.549    0.549    0.549                      
²       178       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
³       179       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
´       180       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
µ       181       0.576    0.576    0.576    0.576                      
¶       182       0.537    0.556    0.537    0.556                      
·       183       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
¸       184       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
¹       185       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
º       186       0.365    0.365    0.365    0.365                      
»       187       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
¼       188       0.834    0.834    0.834    0.834                      
½       189       0.834    0.834    0.834    0.834                      
¾       190       0.834    0.834    0.834    0.834                      
¿       191       0.611    0.611    0.611    0.611                      
À       192       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
Á       193       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
Â       194       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
Ã       195       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
Ä       196       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
Å       197       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
Æ       198       1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000                      
Ç       199       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
È       200       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
É       201       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
Ê       202       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
Ë       203       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
Ì       204       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
Í       205       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
Î       206       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
Ï       207       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
Ð       208       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ñ       209       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ò       210       0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778                      
Ó       211       0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778                      
Ô       212       0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778                      
Õ       213       0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778                      
Ö       214       0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778                      
×       215       0.584    0.584    0.584    0.584                      
Ø       216       0.778    0.778    0.778    0.778                      
Ù       217       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ú       218       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Û       219       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ü       220       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ý       221       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
Þ       222       0.667    0.667    0.667    0.667                      
ß       223       0.611    0.611    0.611    0.611                      
à       224       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
á       225       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
â       226       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
ã       227       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
ä       228       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
å       229       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
æ       230       0.889    0.889    0.889    0.889                      
ç       231       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
è       232       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
é       233       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
ê       234       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
ë       235       0.556    0.556    0.556    0.556                      
ì       236       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
í       237       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
î       238       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
ï       239       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
ð       240       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ñ       241       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ò       242       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ó       243       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ô       244       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
õ       245       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ö       246       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
÷       247       0.549    0.549    0.549    0.549                      
ø       248       0.611    0.611    0.611    0.611                      
ù       249       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ú       250       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
û       251       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ü       252       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ý       253       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
þ       254       0.556    0.611    0.556    0.611                      
ÿ       255       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      

times
char    unicode   normal   bold     italic   bolditalic
        32        0.250    0.250    0.250    0.250                      
!       33        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.389                      
"       34        0.408    0.555    0.420    0.555                      
#       35        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
$       36        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
%       37        0.833    1.000    0.833    0.833                      
&       38        0.778    0.833    0.778    0.778                      
'       39        0.180    0.278    0.214    0.278                      
(       40        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
)       41        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
*       42        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
+       43        0.564    0.570    0.675    0.570                      
,       44        0.250    0.250    0.250    0.250                      
-       45        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
.       46        0.250    0.250    0.250    0.250                      
/       47        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
0       48        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
1       49        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
2       50        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
3       51        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
4       52        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
5       53        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
6       54        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
7       55        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
8       56        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
9       57        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
:       58        0.278    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
;       59        0.278    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
<       60        0.564    0.570    0.675    0.570                      
=       61        0.564    0.570    0.675    0.570                      
>       62        0.564    0.570    0.675    0.570                      
?       63        0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
@       64        0.921    0.930    0.920    0.832                      
A       65        0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
B       66        0.667    0.667    0.611    0.667                      
C       67        0.667    0.722    0.667    0.667                      
D       68        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
E       69        0.611    0.667    0.611    0.667                      
F       70        0.556    0.611    0.611    0.667                      
G       71        0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
H       72        0.722    0.778    0.722    0.778                      
I       73        0.333    0.389    0.333    0.389                      
J       74        0.389    0.500    0.444    0.500                      
K       75        0.722    0.778    0.667    0.667                      
L       76        0.611    0.667    0.556    0.611                      
M       77        0.889    0.944    0.833    0.889                      
N       78        0.722    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
O       79        0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
P       80        0.556    0.611    0.611    0.611                      
Q       81        0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
R       82        0.667    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
S       83        0.556    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
T       84        0.611    0.667    0.556    0.611                      
U       85        0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
V       86        0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
W       87        0.944    1.000    0.833    0.889                      
X       88        0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
Y       89        0.722    0.722    0.556    0.611                      
Z       90        0.611    0.667    0.556    0.611                      
[       91        0.333    0.333    0.389    0.333                      
\       92        0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
]       93        0.333    0.333    0.389    0.333                      
^       94        0.469    0.581    0.422    0.570                      
_       95        0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
`       96        0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
a       97        0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
b       98        0.500    0.556    0.500    0.500                      
c       99        0.444    0.444    0.444    0.444                      
d       100       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.500                      
e       101       0.444    0.444    0.444    0.444                      
f       102       0.333    0.333    0.278    0.333                      
g       103       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
h       104       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
i       105       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
j       106       0.278    0.333    0.278    0.278                      
k       107       0.500    0.556    0.444    0.500                      
l       108       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
m       109       0.778    0.833    0.722    0.778                      
n       110       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
o       111       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
p       112       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.500                      
q       113       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.500                      
r       114       0.333    0.444    0.389    0.389                      
s       115       0.389    0.389    0.389    0.389                      
t       116       0.278    0.333    0.278    0.278                      
u       117       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
v       118       0.500    0.500    0.444    0.444                      
w       119       0.722    0.722    0.667    0.667                      
x       120       0.500    0.500    0.444    0.500                      
y       121       0.500    0.500    0.444    0.444                      
z       122       0.444    0.444    0.389    0.389                      
{       123       0.480    0.394    0.400    0.348                      
|       124       0.200    0.220    0.275    0.220                      
}       125       0.480    0.394    0.400    0.348                      
~       126       0.541    0.520    0.541    0.570                      
€       128       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
‚       130       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
ƒ       131       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
„       132       0.444    0.500    0.556    0.500                      
…       133       1.000    1.000    0.889    1.000                      
†       134       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
‡       135       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ˆ       136       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
‰       137       1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000                      
Š       138       0.556    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
‹       139       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
Œ       140       0.889    1.000    0.944    0.944                      
Ž       142       0.611    0.667    0.556    0.611                      
‘       145       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
’       146       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
“       147       0.444    0.500    0.556    0.500                      
”       148       0.444    0.500    0.556    0.500                      
•       149       0.350    0.350    0.350    0.350                      
–       150       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
—       151       1.000    1.000    0.889    1.000                      
˜       152       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
™       153       0.980    1.000    0.980    1.000                      
š       154       0.389    0.389    0.389    0.389                      
›       155       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
œ       156       0.722    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
ž       158       0.444    0.444    0.389    0.389                      
Ÿ       159       0.722    0.722    0.556    0.611                      
        160       0.250    0.250    0.250    0.250                      
¡       161       0.333    0.333    0.389    0.389                      
¢       162       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
£       163       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
¤       164       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
¥       165       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
¦       166       0.200    0.220    0.275    0.220                      
§       167       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
¨       168       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
©       169       0.760    0.747    0.760    0.747                      
ª       170       0.276    0.300    0.276    0.266                      
«       171       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
¬       172       0.564    0.570    0.675    0.606                      
-       173       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
®       174       0.760    0.747    0.760    0.747                      
¯       175       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
°       176       0.400    0.400    0.400    0.400                      
±       177       0.549    0.549    0.549    0.549                      
²       178       0.300    0.300    0.300    0.300                      
³       179       0.300    0.300    0.300    0.300                      
´       180       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
µ       181       0.576    0.576    0.576    0.576                      
¶       182       0.453    0.540    0.523    0.500                      
·       183       0.333    0.333    0.250    0.250                      
¸       184       0.333    0.333    0.333    0.333                      
¹       185       0.300    0.300    0.300    0.300                      
º       186       0.310    0.330    0.310    0.300                      
»       187       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
¼       188       0.750    0.750    0.750    0.750                      
½       189       0.750    0.750    0.750    0.750                      
¾       190       0.750    0.750    0.750    0.750                      
¿       191       0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
À       192       0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
Á       193       0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
Â       194       0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
Ã       195       0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
Ä       196       0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
Å       197       0.722    0.722    0.611    0.667                      
Æ       198       0.889    1.000    0.889    0.944                      
Ç       199       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.667                      
È       200       0.611    0.667    0.611    0.667                      
É       201       0.611    0.667    0.611    0.667                      
Ê       202       0.611    0.667    0.611    0.667                      
Ë       203       0.611    0.667    0.611    0.667                      
Ì       204       0.333    0.389    0.333    0.389                      
Í       205       0.333    0.389    0.333    0.389                      
Î       206       0.333    0.389    0.333    0.389                      
Ï       207       0.333    0.389    0.333    0.389                      
Ð       208       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ñ       209       0.722    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
Ò       210       0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
Ó       211       0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
Ô       212       0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
Õ       213       0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
Ö       214       0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
×       215       0.564    0.570    0.675    0.570                      
Ø       216       0.722    0.778    0.722    0.722                      
Ù       217       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ú       218       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Û       219       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ü       220       0.722    0.722    0.722    0.722                      
Ý       221       0.722    0.722    0.556    0.611                      
Þ       222       0.556    0.611    0.611    0.611                      
ß       223       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.500                      
à       224       0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
á       225       0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
â       226       0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ã       227       0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ä       228       0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
å       229       0.444    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
æ       230       0.667    0.722    0.667    0.722                      
ç       231       0.444    0.444    0.444    0.444                      
è       232       0.444    0.444    0.444    0.444                      
é       233       0.444    0.444    0.444    0.444                      
ê       234       0.444    0.444    0.444    0.444                      
ë       235       0.444    0.444    0.444    0.444                      
ì       236       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
í       237       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
î       238       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
ï       239       0.278    0.278    0.278    0.278                      
ð       240       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ñ       241       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
ò       242       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ó       243       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ô       244       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
õ       245       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ö       246       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
÷       247       0.549    0.549    0.549    0.549                      
ø       248       0.500    0.500    0.500    0.500                      
ù       249       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
ú       250       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
û       251       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
ü       252       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.556                      
ý       253       0.500    0.500    0.444    0.444                      
þ       254       0.500    0.556    0.500    0.500                      
ÿ       255       0.500    0.500    0.444    0.444                      

courier
All characters in every style are 0.600 (font is monospaced)
```

Once you have determined the width of your string with the above table you need to convert the answer to your desired unit of measurement.

```
width (in inches) = (character or string width * font size) / (72 pt/in)
width (in mm) = (character or string width * font size * 25.4 mm/in) / (72 pt/in)
```

The only caveat to using the above I could think of was if your output pdf was making use of kerning pairs. My output files did not appear to be using kerning pairs, so I did not explore the issue further. If for some reason this is an issue for you, you would need to adjust your widths slightly for each kerning pair as it occurred.

The calculation of height is much less involved. The height of a single line of text is simply the font size. A line of text at size 10 will take up 10 pt.

If you are wanting to calculate multiple lines of text you will need to account for the "line height" (essentially the amount of whitespace between lines). In my testing I found that jsPDF uses a default line height of 115% (1.15x) of the font size. Thus your calculation of line height would become:

```
height = font size * number of lines * line height

Example:
height = 10 pt * 5 lines * 1.15
height = 57.5 pt
```

You then simply convert to your desired unit of measurement as above.

Comment: Just to add to the information here, by passing in an object as the first parameter of the constructor, you can set the line height explicitly:

`var doc = new jsPDF({orientation: 'p', lineHeight: 1.3, unit: 'pt'});`


Also, regarding font height: The actual character height will vary from the font size (usually smaller). This answer gives a bit more detail: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/4069

Comment: how did you go about getting the individual character widths you used in your table?

Comment: It was a while ago, but I believe I printed out 1000 of each character in a PDF and then printed vertical lines at specific intervals to "measure" with total width. After that I divided by 1000 to get the width of a single character. I believe I did eventually find the actual values in the source font files that confirmed my original calculations, but I unfortunately do not recall exactly where I found them.

Answer (score 8):

It's now included in jsPDF:

```
doc.getTextWidth(text);
```