# rich text formatting in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I tried to put a text from a JSON together in JSPDF with a "Lable" which is supposed to be BOLD and a comment which should be written normally.

so something like this:

**LABLE**:COMENTAR

**LABLE2**:COMENTAR2

**LABLE3**:COMENTAR3

I have tried following:

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFont("Helvetica");
doc.setFontSize(25);

var comDim= doc.getTextDimensions(coment.coment);
var labledim = doc.getTextDimensions(coment.lable);

doc.setFontStyle('bold');
doc.text(21, currentDistance, '- '+coment.lable+':');
doc.setFontStyle('normal');
doc.text(labledim.w, currentDistance, coment.coment);

doc.save('Storecheck.pdf');
```

which brings me the following result:

[image: Result]

But the gaps between the label and the comment are too big and unfortunately, the text is not wrapped. Which is really bad because I can't say how long the text is.

I would be very grateful for a hint or approach, maybe there is an example somewhere.

Comment: A "lable"? is that like a little lab? :-D

Comment: thank you for this 3 year old question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why there is a gap between the "label" and the "comment". What texts are stored in `coment`? Might they be padded with whitespaces or tabs? In that case you might want to `.trim()` your texts before adding them to the pdf ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)).

For word wrapping you can use `doc.splitTextToSize` before passing the text itself to `doc.text`. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272058/word-wrap-in-generated-pdf-using-jspdf).

I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tbrpo30f/

Comment: Hi Fabian,
the **coments** are just simple texts with no Tab or  whitespaces :-(

Comment: Could you try to create a fiddle or provide some more of your code? My example works fine so the issue has to be somewhere else...

Comment: hi fabian Basically, I have something like that:
https://jsfiddle.net/frief/L57fh9bz/16/#&togetherjs=5ih6LpTIHK

Comment: For some reason, the Labledim.w is wrong it is 140 but sould be 76

Comment: According to this post the result highly depends on the unit system you are using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25675981/4528518. I worked a bit on your fiddle and got slightly better results but I think you are better off if you use some build-in features like `fromHTML` or tables... 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25675981/4528518

Comment: var htmlString ="<b>- "+lable+" </b>"+ coment.coment;
doc.fromHTML(htmlString,21,currentDistance-7,{});

with fromHTML I have the problem that neither the font nor the line break works :-(

Comment: The formulas from the last post are doing relatively well..
I still have small gaps but it works.
I would wish that it is easier

Comment: @FabianScheidt thanks for the fiddle :) helped me big time 3 years later while pulling an all nighter